# Bootstrap SASS and Autoprefixer in Netbeans

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, netbeans, sass, autoprefixer

I'm using the SASS official port of Bootstrap in a NetBeans web project.

Now, the Bootstrap site states "If you're compiling Bootstrap from its Less/Sass source and not using our Gruntfile, you'll need to integrate Autoprefixer into your build process yourself." https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

I don't know how to/if I can do that in NetBeans.

I counted the number of instances "webkit" was found in the original precompiled Bootstrap version bootstrap.css and in the creatated css-version when compiling the SASS Bootstrap files in NetBeans. The numbers were 92 vs 76. So, there are still lots of prefixes in the SASS version, but not all.

So, my question is, assuming I do want all original prefix additions:

Can I use the Autoprefixer in NetBeans, and how do I do that, or am I forced to do that externally NetBeans on my own SASS-compiled css-files?

Thanks.